# How to use io to generate in memory data streams as file like objects?

Tags: python, file, io, temporary-files

I like to generate a in-memory (temp file)  data stream in Python. One thread is filling the stream with data, and a other one consumes it.

After checking the [io - Core tools for working with streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) , it seems to me that the `io` module is the best choice for it.

So I put a simple example for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8

import io

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = io.BytesIO()
    a.write("hello".encode())
    txt = a.read(100)
    txt = txt.decode("utf-8")
    print(txt)
```

My example does not work. `"hello"` is not written to a and can not be read after. So were is my error? How do I have to alter my code to get a file like object in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dhilmathy and @ShadowRanger mentioned that `io.BytesIO()` do not have separate read and write pointer.

I overcome this problem with creating a simple class that implements a read pointer and remembers the amount of bytes written. When the amount of read bytes is equal the amount of written bytes the file is shrink to save memory.

My solution so far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8

import io

class memoryStreamIO(io.BytesIO):
    """
    memoryStreamIO

    a in memory file like stream object 
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._wIndex = 0
        self._rIndex = 0
        self._mutex = threading.Lock()

    def write(self, d : bytearray):
        self._mutex.acquire()
        r = super().write(d)
        self._wIndex += len(d)
        self._mutex.release()
        return r

    def read(self, n : int):
        self._mutex.acquire()
        super().seek(self._rIndex)
        r = super().read(n)
        self._rIndex += len(r)
        # now we are checking if we can
        if self._rIndex == self._wIndex:
            super().truncate(0)
            super().seek(0)
            self._rIndex = 0
            self._wIndex = 0
        self._mutex.release()
        return r

    def seek(self, n):
        self._mutex.acquire()
        self._rIndex = n
        r = super().seek(n)
        self._mutex.release()
        return r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = streamIO()

    a.write("hello".encode())
    txt = (a.read(100)).decode()
    print(txt)

    a.write("abc".encode())
    txt = (a.read(100)).decode()
    print(txt)
```

Comment: I don't think this is how the file interface is supposed to work. What you want is a pipe --- two ends, one end readable, the other end writable.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's written; but reading is the problem. You should be referring to [class io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). You can get the value using `getvalue()`. Like,

```
import io

a = io.BytesIO()
a.write("hello".encode())
txt = a.getvalue()
txt = txt.decode("utf-8")
print(txt)
```

Comment: merci - I like to handle my io instance like a file - only write and read. Seems that I have to use a other io class

Comment: @StefanJaritz: If you want to use it in a file-like way, `a.seek(0)` before the `a.read(100)` would also work; the `write` moves the file pointer, so you need to move it back to the beginning of the "file" to have `read` pick up what you just wrote.

Comment: is there a io class having separate read & write file pointers? Like a fifo?