# How to use StringIO with independent read and write pointer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

In my Python program, and there in a thread, I'm constantly and asynchronously getting a raw-byte buffer (a log output, actually) from an embedded device. After conversion, it is an ascii-string containing linebreaks.

In the same program I would like to consume it as lines from the main-thread, from time to time.

I chose `io.StringIO` for this as is does the linebreaks-to-lines split and has the nice `readline`-interface.

In my thread I'm calling `write()` on the StringIO-object and the main thread would want to consume lines from time to time (via `readline()`)

However, the StringIO-class does not behave as a FIFO or Ringbuffer. It does not have a separate read and write-pointer.

Before readline() I'd have to move the file-point back to the last read position and when done back to the end, so that the write will append correctly.

I could write my own string-line-ring-buffer with that interface taking into account the concurrent access and so on. But it is a hard task actually and I'm wondering whether is already something which fulfills my needs.

Comment: can't you use normal list or [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) ? One thread can put data to the end of queue and other thread can get data from the beginning of queue. `Queue` is often used to communicate threads.

Comment: Then I would have to parse the strings and combine lines from previous buffers and so on. Exactly the work StringIO is doing perfectly.

Comment: why do you have to combine with previouse buffer ? You can send item to queue and other thread can get next item from queue and then use it with previous content or not.

Comment: Because the incoming buffer-blocks are not per-line. It is just data that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Related: [python - How to use io to generate in memory data streams as file like objects? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183096/how-to-use-io-to-generate-in-memory-data-streams-as-file-like-objects)

Answer (score 1):

`io.StringIO` is unsuitable as a buffer for a stream because as you already mentioned, it does not behave like a FIFO or a ring buffer.

Instead, you can create your own streamable FIFO buffer with a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object:

```
from typing import IO
from collections import deque
from io import BufferedIOBase

class BinaryStream(BufferedIOBase, IO[bytes]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = deque()

    def read1(self, size=-1):
        return bytes(self.buffer.popleft() for _ in range(min(size, len(self.buffer))))

    def write(self, value):
        self.buffer.extend(value)

    readable = writable = lambda self: True
```

so that you can use the convenient [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) over the streamable FIFO buffer to read any raw bytes written to the stream as lines as they are ready:

```
from time import sleep
from random import random
from itertools import count
from threading import Thread
from io import TextIOWrapper

def writer():
    c = count()
    while True:
        sleep(random() * 2)
        value = next(c) # replace this with your log reader
        print('writing', value)
        raw_stream.write(f'{value}\n'.encode())

def reader():
    while True:
        while line := stream.readline():
            print('read', line, end='')
        sleep(1)

raw_stream = BinaryStream()
stream = TextIOWrapper(raw_stream)
writer_thread = Thread(target=writer)
reader_thread = Thread(target=reader)
writer_thread.start()
reader_thread.start()
writer_thread.join()
reader_thread.join()
```

This would output something like:

```
writing 0
writing 1
read 0
read 1
writing 2
writing 3
read 2
read 3
writing 4
writing 5
read 4
read 5
writing 6
writing 7
writing 8
writing 9
writing 10
read 6
read 7
read 8
read 9
read 10
writing 11
read 11
...
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/LeftWavyTriangle

Comment: I don't think this is how the file interface is supposed to work. What you want is a pipe --- two ends, one end readable, the other end writable.